# Mocha and NightmareJS- continue test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, nightmare

I am running into a simple issue, I have about 5 tests to be part of one group, one of them I am forcing them to fail but I am not able to exit the fail state:

```
.goto(url)
.wait('#element')
.evaluate(fnc...)
wait('#newelement')
....
evaluate(function(){
 return document.querySlector('#myid').innerText
})
.then(function(result) {
result.should.equal('1');// I know I am expecting 2
done();
})
// will never be executed.
.then.....
```

// The following  message is thrown.
Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

It would be OK, however there are other tests that I need to make after this one fails but I can't seem to be able to continue or have an elegant way to report the failure without affecting the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a test to fail you can call `done` passing an error as an argument:

```
done(new Error('this is my error message'))
```

So in your case, something like this:

```
.goto(url)
.wait('#element')
.evaluate(fnc...)
wait('#newelement')
....
evaluate(function(){
 return document.querySlector('#myid').innerText
})
.then(function(result) {
done(new Error('Please test, fail because I want you to.'));
})
// will never be executed.
.then.....
```

Also, as a side note, your original code might not work, because of multiple calls to `evaluate` on the same chain call, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292143/nightmarejs-multiple-evaluations) answer for more details.